# Как остановить sql запрос?

Tags: база-данных, sql

Есть формочка, заполняется и по кнопочке отправляется запрос в бд.
В базе таблицы миллионники, и поэтому иногда результата приходится ждать очень долго. Собственно суть: заполнил форму, нажал кнопку, запрос пошел, и если нажавший копку передумал получать результаты, как можно остановить, прекратить поиск в базе???

Comment: // system('/etc/init.d/mysqld restart'); // шутка, конечно, вариант для отморозков при вешающем запросе в минуту)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Узнать pid процесса по ps -ax и сделать ему kill.

Зависит от того, что у вас за база данных: в MySQL транзакция останавливается при потере связи с клиентом.

Comment: Мне уже интересно. Как же это сделать по-подробнее. Что такое "ps -ax", как это сделать программно, или в SQL-запросе??? Тут же, если вопрос задали, то значит не ориентируются в продвинутых знаниях. Или в данном вопросе и что его касается. Или как это сделать. А идеи могут быть на столько поверхностны или углубленны, что ответ будет выглядеть как тупо набор слов.

Comment: ps -ax - обыкновенная nix-совская команда.

Ответьте на вопрос , какая у вас база данных. В постгресе под фрёй я снимаю большие транзакции именно так.

Comment: Вы определенно хороший программист! Но имейте уважение! Говорите по-русски! Т.е. так, чтобы Вас понимали хоть и не все,но большинство. Я впервые даже слышу (может это мне в минус) про "постгресе", "фрёй" "nix-совская команда". Может быть я слишком не продвинутый. Но тут же спрашивают вроде не слишком продвинутые? (по крайней мере большинство, как я предполагаю).

Comment: Я задал вопрос про базу данных. Какая именно у вас?

Comment: Ну это уже @namak должен ответить. А я заинтересовался потому, что знать это довольно полезно. И захотел научиться. Может, надо предположить, что база ЛЮБАЯ. И как же в этом случае действовать?

Comment: общего решения для любой БД нет

Comment: Со всеми эти прекращениями запроса (ps ax -> kill) можно баловаться, если не происходит изменения данных. Иначе в лучшем (begin transaction ... end transaction) случае вы получаете rollback (что в известной песенке называется небезопасным), либо нарушение целостности данных. Если только выборка (select) данных, то надо смотреть подробнее, но всё равно бяка -> перепроектируйте базу, чтобы такие запросы были быстрее.

Comment: СУБД Sybase, как это сделать на стороне клиента, так называемую кнопку "Отменить" или "Остановить запрос".

P.S.: тока не пишите как сделать кнопочку...надо остановить запрос убить его не получится, не столько прав.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, что функция отправляющая запрос просто не возвращает управление, поэтому программа стоит и нельзя ничего сделать.
Организуйте отправку запроса в отдельном потоке, а при желании остановить просто завершайте поток.

Comment: Ну дак а транзакция в БД все равно же исполняться будет? Т.е. если программа отправила запрос и ждет ответа. Потом, когда ее остановили, программа больше не ждет ответ, а база данных дальше, по-идее, будет выполнять команду, которую ей задали.

Comment: Если запрос работает в отдельном потоке, то программа не ждет ответа, она ждет сигнала от потока о том, что запрос выполнен. Можно этот поток завершить принудительно. Но важно чтобы обращение к базе было правильно организовано. Если запрос на изменение данных, вначале должна быть открыта транзакция.

Конкретная реализация зависит от того, на чем пишется сама программа, и от того, с каким СУБД она работает.

Если обращение к БД реализована в основном потоке, то, увы, вариантов нет.

Answer (score 1):

Зависит сильно от того, какая база и версии базы, к примеру, в Firebird 2.5 запрос можно грохнуть средствами самого сервера, а то же Firebitd 2.1 не может такое сделать.
Самое правильное в данном случае, если запрос выполняется непозволительно долго, пересмотреть его.

Comment: СУБД Sybase

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы используете ADO.NET, у IDbCommand есть метод Cancel().